# Stuck on a Python 3 Parable iteration

Tags: python-3.x

Well, we got parables exam preparations and instead of me typing everything a million times, I thought of rather making a little Python script. It's done, but something's bugged. I've been stuck on it for around 30 minutes and just can't figure it out as my Python is a bit rusty.

You can find my code at: https://repl.it/@Rrrei/CurvySecondaryService

Comment: parabel: y=ax²+bx+c  and please rename variables on `x in x`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, `for x in x:` is indeed bad naming :p. You can easily get confused about what `x` you are talking about, the inner or the outer one.
Also a = input(..) makes a a string, a string multiplied by a number repeats the string in Python. e.g.:

```
'1'*5 == '11111'
```

To solve this, wrap input in a int: `a=int(input(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to append the string values. Python is not typesafe and `a` is a string after calling `input()`...

Here you can see a safe example with corrected values and better names (cleancode).
[check my code](https://repl.it/repls/ExcellentSaddlebrownFactors)

It´s the correct version of yours.
If you want the same form `b=0` `c=0`....